# Binding FontAwesome to a ::before with unicode - displays crypdo-icon

Tags: html, css, unicode, font-awesome, contao

I am trying to include FontAwesome to an ::before-element.
The include to the website worked (I have other Icons in an i-element on the website) but the unicode-way won't work.

I've  trying to add an icon for the previous-button in fontAwesome like that:

```
    .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next, .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev, .owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev::before{
    content: "\f053";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

But it just shows up like that:

[image: Error]

I tested adding height and width, making it a block-element.. nothing seems to work. I am using the Contao CMS.

Comment: Which version of fontawesome are you using? The new version requires you to set the weight which is different per glyph, for chevron left that's`font-weight: bold;`

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa I'm using version 5 and tried it with hte font-weight, but there's no change.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa You can check that here: https://vacationy.siteholder.de  (Bottom)

Comment: When I insert `<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>` before your button via dev tools and then inspect it, it shows the font-family for the `i` element as `"Font Awesome 5 Free"` - you used `FontAwesome` for your button ::before element instead.

Comment: I have FontAwesome installed locally so my computer is finding and displaying the right icon, it feels like you're missing the font on your site, are you sure you're including it?

Comment: @CBroe Oh,, Changed it to "Font Awesome 5 Free" and now it's working... Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa I also included it locally on the server, but it was the wrong font-family.. It's now working, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I insert `<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>` before your button via dev tools and then inspect it, it shows the font-family for the `i` element as `"Font Awesome 5 Free"` - you used `FontAwesome` for your button `::before` element instead.